# iphone default map app open with different language

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, dictionary

I successfully open Iphone default app with current user location but if user has selected a different language (e.g.. for Dutch Current Location = Aktueller Ort) then current location and route is totally wrong.

```
NSString *mystr=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=Destination"];
NSURL *myurl=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:mystr];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myurl];
```

Although we can detect current language and match using switch case but we need to translate "Current Location" to all supported languages by iphone map app.

I tried [wiki link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html) for parameters and found **hl** parameter but not worked for me I think method for apply parameter by me is wrong or something.

So how can I open map app with particular fix language like english even when user selected different language?

thanx for any help!

Comment: Just to say: "Aktueller Ort" is German, "Huidige locatie" is Dutch.

Comment: yes,@rckoenes you are right but if we set iphone language to dutch and open Map app we have to write Aktueller Ort to access our current location.anyway please help me for this and thanx for reply

Comment: Any other way to open Iphone default map app with user's current location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the current user location by the Core Location Framework and pass latitude and longitude to the google maps url. Or you can check the current language and translate "Current Location" in a lot of lang and pass it to the url.

```
NSString *language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: As I written in question we need to find word "Current Location" in all languages and set that word in url but any other way?

Comment: Get the current location before you call the url. With Core Location you can get the user location and then get the coordinates you can pass to the url. The coordinates will replace the "Current Location" word. Is it clear?