# change language of google maps with swift 4 on xcode 9.2

Tags: xcode, google-maps, swift4

I Wanna to change the Label language of **Google Maps** on **Swift** that I Installed with CocoaPods. Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default the API will attempt to load the most appropriate language based on the users location or browser settings. Some APIs allow you to explicitly set a language when you make a request.

From there, you may add language parameter in your HTTPS request in some Google Maps APIs. However, for some APIs that doesn't allow this, you have to first determine the current location with the use of [Core Location Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation) as suggested in this SO post - [iphone default map app open with different language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746298/iphone-default-map-app-open-with-different-language).

Reference - [How to change the language on GoogleMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38075630/how-to-change-the-language-on-googlemap)